# Finite, normal subgroups of reductive groups in positive characteristic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, characteristic-p

Consider the following statement about a connected, reductive group $G$ over a field $k$:

> Every finite, normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is central.

In characteristic $0$, this is true, and the proof is easy:  since $N$ is smooth, it suffices to show that $N(\overline k)$ is contained in $Z(G)(\overline k)$; so we can consider, for $n \in N(\overline k)$, the orbit map $g \mapsto g n g^{-1}$ on $G_{\overline k}$, whose image is a connected subscheme of $N_{\overline k}$, hence equals the singleton $\{n\}$.

One cannot reason in the same way in positive characteristic, since not every subgroup scheme of $G$ is smooth.  Is the statement nonetheless still true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, it turns out that I already knew the answer to this, in a different context.

This can fail in characteristic $2$:  the kernel of the exceptional isogeny $\operatorname{SO}_{2n + 1} \to \operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ is not central.  I originally supposed that this sort of exceptional behavior might be peculiar to characteristic $2$ (a supposition to which @YCor responded in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412337/finite-normal-subgroups-of-reductive-groups-in-positive-characteristic/412340#comment1056681_412340)), but @FriedrichKnop points out in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412337/finite-normal-subgroups-of-reductive-groups-in-positive-characteristic/412340#comment1056714_412340) that it is not so: in any non-$0$ characteristic, the kernel of the Frobenius isogeny is not central.

Comment: Where does the fact in odd characteristic come from?

Comment: The Frobenius kernel is not central either.

Comment: The problem is solved by Chevalley's classification of isogenies.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop, thanks!  (So my claim that the statement is true in odd characteristic is false.)  I do not know where to look for Chevalley's classification of isogenies (although his language is comparatively modern, I find it hard to look up results in his papers).  Do you know a modern exposition, or a specific reference in Chevalley?

Comment: Springer, T. A. Linear algebraic groups. Second edition. Theorem 9.6.5.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop, ah, sure, thanks.  Of course in principle [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412337/finite-normal-subgroups-of-reductive-groups-in-positive-characteristic/412340#comment1057201_412340) solves the issue, but I was wondering if there were a list of in some sense 'indecomposable' non-central isogenies, say, defined on absolutely simple groups.  For example, Steinberg's paper on the isomorphism and isogeny theorems says (§4.11) that the only non-trivial such isogeny that is an isomorphism on tori is the exceptional one I [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1057250)

Comment: [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412337/finite-normal-subgroups-of-reductive-groups-in-positive-characteristic/412340#comment1057248_412340) mentioned.  Are all non-central isogenies somehow built from central ones, the Frobenius, and the exceptional isogeny in characteristic $2$, or are there other 'interesting' examples, whatever 'interesting' means?

Comment: Yes that's true if you include the exceptional isogeny of $G_2$ in characteristic $3$.